# failed to run Hello World project with launching emulaotor

Tags: android

When Start running Android Hello world project, the eclipse launches emulator, but seems hello world project was not running, the emulator showed "Android" in the middle of the scrren, I tried Android 2.2 emulator, I heard some people opens emulator first then run the project, Havn't tried that yet. is that a correct way?

Answer (score 2):

The Android emulator is **slow**. So be patient and eventually it will show you a home screen and your project will run.